# Is it possible to create a many to many relations ship on the same object in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, data-modeling

Our customers have inter relations between them as: suppliers-buyers
meaning: we sell to both suppliers and buyers in the industry we work in.

I am trying to store that relation ship of our customers (between them) in salesforce. It is kind of a Many-to-Many relation. So on every Account I want to have a related list of all it's Buyers it sells to, and also Sellers it buys from (and vice versa on the others account)

I tried with a Junction Object- but I can't create 2 Master-Detail relations on the same object (mainly Account).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

A junction object would be the way to go with this — why do you need to use Master Detail relationships? Lookup fields should suffice in this scenario.

Sometimes in these situations you want to be able to see the full list of related objects without having to have the two possible related lists shown on the page (ones where the object you're viewing is referenced by lookup A, and ones where it's referenced by B) — in this scenario you can use a trigger to create the opposite junction record anytime one is created.

**Basic Setup**

The schema would look like this:

```
    Account >-- lookup A -- Junction Object -- Lookup B --< Account
```

And you may insert two junction records like so:

```
           Lookup A      Lookup B
    ------------------------------
    J1  |  Account 1  |  Account 3
    J2  |  Account 2  |  Account 1
```

With this setup you'd need two related lists on the Account page to see both B and C when viewing record A.

**Trigger Setup**

If you create a trigger to generated the automatic reciprocal as mentioned above, you'd have these records in the junction object:

```
           Lookup A      Lookup B
    ------------------------------
    J1  |  Account 1  |  Account 3
    J2  |  Account 3  |  Account 1
    J3  |  Account 2  |  Account 1
    J4  |  Account 1  |  Account 2
```

Obviously this creates redundant data, but now you need only add one related list of junction objects to the account page layout to see all of the related records.

Comment: Thanks, looks neat. I'll have to decide if I want a 1 or 2 related lists than. I think I will add a third custom field on the junction - to show the relation - but that is not a 2-way view - so might be a problem.

Comment: You could have the third field displayed on the related lists with whichever option you choose — shouldn't be a problem!