# Creating Many to Many relationship between the accounts records in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

Is there any way through which we can relate 1 account record with other account records in a many to many relationship format in salesforce? This is not possible as per the standard way, as we can not create many-to-many relationship with the same object type in salesforce. Can anyone pls suggest some custom way/code to do this?
I have a requirement where I need to link for eg: Account A with Account B and Account C so that I can see the contacts of Account B and C on Account A.
Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create a many to many relations ship on the same object in Salesforce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349850/is-it-possible-to-create-a-many-to-many-relations-ship-on-the-same-object-in-sal)

Answer (score 0):

To create a many-many relationship in salesforce you would need a joiner object that has two master-details to account (There is actually already a standard object called Partner that may fit your needs).

To see the contacts of related accounts it's probably easiest to create a simple visualforce page that will query the contacts of related accounts and display them.

Comment: We dont want to use the Partner object. Any other way to do this?

Comment: Yes, you can create a custom joiner object that has a master-detail relationship to account and a lookup to account (you can make the lookup required).

Comment: These objects that facilitate M:M relationships are formally called "junction objects", so use that term when searching for further help. [This page](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=relationships_manytomany.htm&language=en) shows good information. But using 2 "master-detail" fields is not required, it can be 1 master-detail and 1 lookup, or just 2 lookups.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a relationship between two account objects using a join object.  You must use two lookup field type to relate the objects - a master detail relationship will not work if you are trying to relate the same object.

As per the comment by @grigriforce this can also be done as a master-detail with Account and a Lookup as well as two Lookups.